# How to use script from template in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I create template for gitlab-ci with script

```
.test-script: &test
    - echo "hello"
```

How to use this script in .gitlab-ci.yml? I tried like this

```
include: '/templates/test-template.yml'

example-stage:
  script:
    - *test
```

Error occurs *"This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: Unknown alias: test."* because there is no alias for this script in the merged YAML.

GitLab version: GitLab Community Edition 14.6.0

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65276547/3535187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use GitLab's extends or reference keywords?

```
---
include:
  - local: '/templates/test-template.yml'

example-stage:
  script:
    - !reference [.test-script, script]
```

or

```
---
include:
  - local: '/templates/test-template.yml'

example-stage:
  extends: .test-script
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this syntax :

```
.test-script: &test-script
   script:
     - echo "hello"
```

For your example-stage job :

```
example-stage:
  <<: *test-script
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work if the script is in another .yml with a template. The way from @Jakob Liskow answer worked for my case. P.S. I wrote a comment yesterday that the link helped, but my comment was deleted.